# Textbox_Drop event doesn't update property in ViewModel

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, drag-and-drop

I have a WPF Application with `Framework = .NET 6.0`, and I'm using the `CommunityToolkit.Mvvm` for my MVVM implementation. I need to create a text box where a user can drag and drop a folder, and in my `ViewModel` I need to grab this path. I've tried to implement this using a combination of `MVVM` pattern and some code behind in my `xaml.cs`, but it's not working quite as expected.

My text box XAML:

```
<TextBox Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1"
         Name="TxtPath"
         AllowDrop="True"
         Drop="TxtPath_Drop"
         PreviewDragOver="TxtPath_PreviewDragOver"
         Text="{Binding PathText}">
</TextBox>
```

xaml.cs Code behind:

```
private void TxtPath_Drop(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
{
    var files = (string[])e.Data.GetData(DataFormats.FileDrop);
    if (files != null && files.Length != 0)
    {
        TxtPath.Text = files[0];
    }
}

private void TxtPath_PreviewDragOver(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
{
    e.Handled = true;
}
```

My ViewModel:

```
[ObservableProperty]
private string? pathText;
```

I expected this to update my `PathText` whenever the drag-and-drop operation changes the text, but it doesn't. I get a `null` value for `PathText` instead. I've confirmed that `files[0]` has a valid path value, and that I can visually see the dropped folder path in the text box as well.

Strange thing is, I have a second method in my code behind where a user can click a [ Browse ] button and then select the folder as well, for which I use the method below, and when that's done the `PathText` in my ViewModel is updates as expected.

```
private void BtnBrowse_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    var folderBrowserDialog = new FolderBrowserDialog();

    if (Directory.Exists(TxtPath.Text))
    {
        folderBrowserDialog.Reset();
        folderBrowserDialog.SelectedPath = TxtPath.Text;
    }

    if (folderBrowserDialog.ShowDialog() == System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK)
    {
        TxtPath.Text = folderBrowserDialog.SelectedPath;
    }
}
```

What am I missing here? Why does the `button_Click` event update the bindings but not the `textbox_Drop` event?

Edit: typo

Comment: "*I get a null value for PathText instead*" - have you checked the value of `files[0]`?

Comment: @Clemens, yes, it has a valid path value, and I can even see the path displayed on the text box when I do the drag-drop. It just doesn't update the value on the VM.

Comment: Perhaps you forgot to set `Text="{Binding PathText, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"`

Comment: @emoacht, that did the trick, thanks! I still don't understand though why updating the text box via `FolderBrwoseDialog` in the button click event updated it even before.

Comment: Also, please post it as an answer so I can accept it. If you can include an answer to my question in the previous comment too, that would be great.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The default value of `TextBox.Text`'s UpdateSourceTrigger is LostFocus and so the binding source will be updated when the TextBox losts focus. See [How to: Control When the TextBox Text Updates the Source](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/wpf/data/how-to-control-when-the-textbox-text-updates-the-source).

The solution would be to set UpdateSourceTrigger PropertyChanged.

```xml
Text="{Binding PathText, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
```

I am not sure what happens in the second case but I guess that sequence somehow changes the focus in your app and triggers the update.